# Casting Predicate<> to a child type

Tags: java, casting, polymorphism, functional-interface

I have a custom implementation of a `Predicate` that I want to use in some operations.
However, I am having a hard type making polymorphism work with it.

After some investigation I wrote the minimal code below to reproduce the problem (which  is a better explanation of the problem than I could describe).

```
class Custom implements Predicate<Integer> {
    int y;
    
    public Custom(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean test(Integer i) {
        return y+i>0;
    }
}


public class Main{
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            Custom c1 = new Custom(5);
            Custom c2 = new Custom(8);
            Custom c = (Custom) c1.and(c2); // faulty line - unable to cast
    }
}
```

I am unsure why the casting fails and how to make it work.

Comment: The result of the default `and` method returns an implementation of `Predicate` which is not aware of your `Custom`. To make it work, override the `and` method in your `Custom`. But usually you should never do such casts but simply prefer `Predicate<T>`.

Comment: @fluffy how to override the `and` ? I made some attempts and failed.  Also, I made the `Custom` class because of the `y` attribute in it (I need to keep some state). Is there an alternative way to go about it ?

Comment: I mean, do you really need to cast to `Custom` rather than to refer it as `Predicate<Integer>`?

Comment: Polymorphism and 'child type' usually applies to usage of `extends` (derived class), not `implements` (implementing an interface). I'm not saying that you should extend `Predicate` but just that there are a couple of things going on here.

Comment: @fluffy the `test` does complex regex matchings depending on the state of the `Custom` object. I should be able to do `custom.sety(newY)` , which affects the test result. Therefore I implemented a custom predicate instead of just using it as in functional programming way.

Comment: @giulian5 Ok, I see, but I would not recommend to use `Custom` that way. Just make your predicates immutable (possibly cached), and not bound to a specific type (lambdas, anonymous classes, method references, whatever you prefer). Yes, it won't be possible to change the predicate state, but it's totally fine not to (simply modify the reference to another predicate). Additionally, to make your approach work, you have to override _all_ default methods (`and`, `or`, `negate` + whatever would be released in Java since version 8).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to preserve state of your `Custom` objects and implement the `Predicate` interface I would suggest to overload the `and`, `or` and `negate` methods. When you combine two `Custom` objects with `and`, `or` or when you call `negate` you will get a `Custom` object as return value. When you combine a `Custom` object with any other implementation of `Predicate<Integer` the methods will still return `Predicate<Integer`:

```
class Custom implements Predicate<Integer> {

    class And extends Custom {

        Custom a;
        Custom b;

        public And(Custom a, Custom b) {
            super((i) -> a.test(i) && b.test(i));
            this.a = a;
            this.b = b;
        }
    }

    class Or extends Custom {

        Custom a;
        Custom b;

        public Or(Custom a, Custom b) {
            super((i) -> a.test(i) || b.test(i));
            this.a = a;
            this.b = b;
        }
    }

    class Not extends Custom {

        Custom custom;

        public Not(Custom custom) {
            super((i) -> !custom.test(i));
            this.custom = custom;
        }
    }

    private final Predicate<Integer> predicate;

    public Custom(int y) {
        this((i) -> y + i > 0);
    }

    private Custom(Predicate<Integer> predicate) {
        this.predicate = predicate;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean test(Integer i) {
        return predicate.test(i);
    }

    public Custom.And and(Custom other) {
        return new Custom.And(this, other);
    }

    public Custom.Or or(Custom other) {
        return new Custom.Or(this, other);
    }

    public Custom.Not negate() {
        return new Custom.Not(this);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a good reason of creating such a type of predicate as it complicates your predicates. However, there are at least 3 different ways that come to my mind "changing" the predicate state.

#### v0 - simply use `java.util.function.Predicate<T>`

```java
final Predicate<String> p1 = "foo"::equals;
final Predicate<String> unit1 = p1.or("bar"::equals);
Assertions.assertTrue(unit1.test("foo"));
Assertions.assertTrue(unit1.test("bar"));
Assertions.assertFalse(unit1.test("baz"));
final Predicate<String> unit2 = p1.or("baz"::equals);
Assertions.assertTrue(unit2.test("foo"));
Assertions.assertTrue(unit2.test("baz"));
```

There is nothing wrong with this code and I would still go with it not implementing any custom classes.

#### v1 - "do cast" in a custom predicate implementation

This still requires all default methods from the `Predicate<T>` interface to be overridden in order not to break in a future Java release.

```java
public abstract class V1MutablePredicate<T, P extends V1MutablePredicate<T, P>>
        implements Predicate<T> {

    @Nullable
    private final Predicate<T> predicate;

    protected V1MutablePredicate(@Nullable final Predicate<T> predicate) {
        this.predicate = predicate;
    }

    protected abstract boolean doTest(T t);

    @Nonnull
    protected abstract P wrap(@Nonnull Predicate<T> predicate);

    @Override
    public final boolean test(final T t) {
        return predicate == null ? doTest(t) : predicate.test(t);
    }

    @Nonnull
    @Override
    public final P and(@Nonnull final Predicate<? super T> other) {
        return wrap(Predicate.super.and(other));
    }

    @Nonnull
    @Override
    public final P negate() {
        return wrap(Predicate.super.negate());
    }

    @Nonnull
    @Override
    public final P or(@Nonnull final Predicate<? super T> other) {
        return wrap(Predicate.super.or(other));
    }

}
```

```java
private static final class Custom
        extends V1MutablePredicate<String, Custom> {

    private String s;

    Custom(final String s) {
        this(null, s);
    }

    private Custom(@Nullable final Predicate<String> predicate, final String s) {
        super(predicate);
        this.s = s;
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean doTest(final String t) {
        return t.equals(s);
    }

    @Nonnull
    @Override
    protected Custom wrap(@Nonnull final Predicate<String> predicate) {
        return new Custom(predicate, s);
    }

}

@Test
public void test() {
    final Custom p1 = new Custom("foo");
    final Custom p2 = new Custom("bar");
    final Custom unit = p1.or(p2);
    Assertions.assertTrue(unit.test("foo"));
    Assertions.assertTrue(unit.test("bar"));
    Assertions.assertFalse(unit.test("baz"));
    p2.s = "baz";
    Assertions.assertTrue(unit.test("foo"));
    Assertions.assertTrue(unit.test("baz"));
}
```

This one seems to be closest to what you want to accomplish.

#### v2 - inject the predicate state from outside

```java
public final class V2MutablePredicate<T, S>
        implements Predicate<T> {

    private final Supplier<? extends S> stateSupplier;
    private final BiPredicate<? super S, ? super T> predicate;

    public V2MutablePredicate(final Supplier<? extends S> stateSupplier, final BiPredicate<? super S, ? super T> predicate) {
        this.stateSupplier = stateSupplier;
        this.predicate = predicate;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean test(final T t) {
        return predicate.test(stateSupplier.get(), t);
    }

}
```

```java
final AtomicReference<String> r1 = new AtomicReference<>("foo");
final V2MutablePredicate<String, String> p1 = new V2MutablePredicate<>(r1::get, String::equals);
final AtomicReference<String> r2 = new AtomicReference<>("bar");
final V2MutablePredicate<String, String> p2 = new V2MutablePredicate<>(r2::get, String::equals);
final Predicate<String> unit = p1.or(p2);
Assertions.assertTrue(unit.test("foo"));
Assertions.assertTrue(unit.test("bar"));
Assertions.assertFalse(unit.test("baz"));
r2.set("baz");
Assertions.assertTrue(unit.test("foo"));
Assertions.assertTrue(unit.test("baz"));
```

This implementation requires the state to be changed from outside managing multiple objects to be handled and it also requires "state" classes, but it does not require the default methods to be overridden and also requires the supplier to provide the value in every `test` method call.